# Apply viewport width size to a div on hover using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs lined up horizontally. Each get their width size from a JQuery update size function. But, instead of loading like this, I want them to load at 300px and animate to viewport size on hover (similar to how the opacity animates on hover).

Here's what I have so far:

http://werdnaworks.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

On each `<div>`s hover `animate()` both `width` and `opacity`. But you also have to set the **parent width** equal to total `<div>`s width so you can keep them inline.

```
var $div = $('div'),
    divW = $div.width(),//300px
    divLen = $div.length,
    windowW = window.innerWidth;

$('body').width(divW*divLen);

$div.hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({width:windowW, opacity:1},'fast');
    $('body').stop().animate({width:windowW+(divW*divLen-1)},'fast');      
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({width:divW, opacity:0.5},'fast');
    $('body').stop().animate({width:divW*divLen},'fast');
});
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/R7n3c/2/).

You may also want to automatically scroll to the `<div>` being hovered. You can do so with animate `scrollLeft`.

```
$div.hover(function(){
    var offsetLeft = $(this).offset().left;
    $(this).stop().animate({width:windowW, opacity:1},'fast');
    $('body').stop().animate({width:windowW+(divW*divLen-1), scrollLeft:offsetLeft},'fast');      
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({width:divW, opacity:0.5},'fast');
    $('body').stop().animate({width:divW*divLen},'fast');
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/R7n3c/1/)